# How to android ndk gradle experimental ffmpeg include?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 1.4.1

gradle version 2.6 (gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha5)

NDK Bulid

How to use ffmpeg lib?

Comment: More details are needed, like what you've tried so far and what the result is. stackoverflow.com is here to answer *specific* programming questions, not general "do my work for me" questions.

Comment: bml, sorry. I am not good at English. I will not question at stackoverflow.com.